# 4 Blue and 4 Red, Take 2

Tags: probability

There is a box. There are 4 blue pens and 4 red pens in the box.

If I take 2 blue pens out, what is the probability? (My answer is 1/3, but my teacher says 1/2)

If I take 1 blue pen and 1 red pen out, what is the probability? (My answer is 1/3, but my teacher says 1/2)

I thought I can take `2 blue` or `2 red` or `1 blue and 1 red`, so my answer is 1/3.

So, whose answer is correct? Explanation?

**I studies math in Chinese language, if my English is wrong, please tell me.

Edit:

If 2 blue pens had taken out, then the 2 blue pens will put back.

Any pen that had taken out will be put back.

Edit 2:

I rewrite my question.

Question 1) A box containing 4 blue pens and 4 red pens.

(a) What is the probability of taking out 2 blue pens?

(b) What is the probability of taking out 1 blue pen and 1 red pen?

Comment: Clarification requested: "If I take 2 blue pens out, what is the probability?"  Please re-state the question.  Are you asking for the probability that if you take 2 pens at random, without replacement, that both pens will be blue?  If not, what are you asking?

Comment: Re previous comment, going forward with your future mathSE questions, please proofread them to see if you have eliminated any ambiguities in the question.

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry for the lack of information, I had edited my question. Any pen that had taken out will be put back.

Comment: Please re-read the posting.  It is still unclear what you are asking.  Pretend that you have never seen the question before, read the posting with fresh eyes, and ask yourself whether your posting will be perfectly clear to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing based on context that when you say "what is the probability" you mean "what is the probability of having one blue and one red pen. Edit based on new information: and apparently you put the first pen back before drawing the second.

If that's right, that means your teacher is right.

My reasoning is this: regardless of which color pen you draw first, you have four pens of that color (since you replace the first pen before redrawing) as well as four of the other color, for a total of eight pens. Since you could draw any pen with equal likelihood, then the odds are 4/8 = 1/2 that you draw the second color.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I had edited my question. Any pen that had taken out will be put back.

Comment: @CHOOYJ thanks, I've updated my answer. I think your teacher is right, then. You can do the experiment yourself if you like, it should only take a few dozen trials before the difference between 1/2 and 1/3 becomes apparent. The famous mathematician Paul Erdos had to see a similar experiment before he was likewise convinced of a simple result in probability theory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did the experiment and found that is 4/8. So, my teacher is right.

Comment: @CHOOYJ Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting $2$ pens without replacement, use the *hypergeometric distribution*.

The first probability is
$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{0}}{\binom{8}{2}}=\frac{6}{28}=\frac{3}{14}.$$

The second probability is
$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}}=\frac{16}{28}=\frac{4}{7}.$$

If you are instead drawing with replacement, the probability of two blues is $(1/2)(1/2)=1/4$, the probability of two reds is also $1/4$, and the probability of one red and one blue is $1-1/4-1/4=1/2$, equivalently, $(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2=1/2$, from red then blue or blue then red.  You have identified three mutually disjoint cases, but they are not equally likely, so the probability of each case is not $1/3$.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I had edited my question. Any pen that had taken out will be put back.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover both without and with replacement.